# Postgres plpgsql JSON assignment

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I'm working with JSONB in Postgres and trying to understand how to correctly perform an assignment to a JSON property in plpgsql.

This query snippet reports a syntax error because of the leading bracket on the assignment, however I was fairly sure this syntax was required to refer to JSON objects in plpgsq:

```
IF (NEW."data")->>'custom' IS NULL THEN
  (NEW."data")->>'custom' := 0;
END IF;
```

This is in a postgresql trigger, so NEW is the provided variable relating to the new database record.

Can someone advise what the correct technique is for assigning a value to a JSON(B) property?

Comment: 9.4...soon to be 9.5.

Answer (score 2):

In **Postgres 9.5** it is quite simple with the function [`jsonb_set()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html):

```
if new.data->>'custom' is null then
    new.data = jsonb_set(new.data::jsonb, '{custom}', '0'::jsonb);
end if;
```

There is no `jsonb_set()` in **Postgres 9.4** so the issue is more complicated:

```
if new.data->>'custom' is null then
    new.data = (
        select json_object_agg(key, value)
        from (
            select key, value
            from jsonb_each(new.data)
            union
            values ('custom', '0'::jsonb)
        ) s
    );
end if;
```